# LibreOffice Calc - MAXIFS by month and year

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I've got a problem with this formula:

```
=MAX.SI.CONJUNTO(Data.K7:K10000;Data.A7:A10000;MES(Datos.A7:A10000)=1;Data.A7:A10000;AÑO(Datos.A7:A10000)=H3)
```

I don't know why it's returning 0.

Basically this is the structure of the formula

```
MAX.SI.CONJUNTO(>max range; range1; criteria1; range2; criteria2; ...)
```

I need to calculate in a cell the maximum value for January and the year 2020. Column A7:A10000 in Data stores dates and column K7:K10000 values.
H3 it's a cell containing the number 2020 for the current year.

I'm using LibreOffice in Spanish so I think MAX.SI.CONJUNTO=MAXIFS  / MES=MONTH   /  AÑO=YEAR

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Thank you for adding the translations so that we don't have to look them up. Using English allows more people to benefit from your question.

Answer (score 0):

For [MAXIFS](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.1/en-US/text/scalc/01/func_maxifs.html), criteria can be a value such as `1` or a range such as `Datos.A7:A10000` but not a function over a range like `MONTH(Datos.A7:A10000)=1`.

Instead, type an [array formula](https://help.libreoffice.org/4.4/Calc/Array_Functions#What_is_an_array_formula.3F) like this in a cell and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
=MAX(IF((MONTH(A7:A10000)=1)*(YEAR(A7:A10000)=H3);K7:K10000;0))
```

Note: Apparently `AND` breaks the array formula, so use `*` instead. This works like `SUMPRODUCT` but with `MAX` instead of `SUM`.